# Stop button when recording audio with AudioRecord

Tags: java, android, audiorecord, android-audiorecord

At the moment I have the code from this site ([link text](http://eurodev.blogspot.com/2009/09/raw-audio-manipulation-in-android.html)) working great. In the example on the site it starts the recording for 10 seconds and then immediately plays the audio back in reverse. I have modified the code to start recording when a button is pressed, but can only get it to record for the 10 seconds and then save that file. I want to be able to start the recording by pressing a button and then stop the recording on a different button press. I have an idea that it could be an interrupt to the wait() method of the thread object but have no idea how to implement this. My code is as follows:

```
public void onClickRecord(View v){
        text.setText("Recording");
        Thread thread = new Thread(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                record();
            }
        });

        thread.start();

        synchronized(this) {
        try {
            wait(10000); //This is the 10 second waiting period while recording
        } 
        catch (InterruptedException e) {
        }
        }

        isRecording = false;

        try {
            thread.join();
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        }

    }
    public void onClickStop(View v){
        //Here is what needs to be implemented to stop the recording.
    }
```

There is quite a bit of code so I have only posted the bits I think are relevant. If any more is needed just ask.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try the AudioRecord Class !
I think that should be helpful.

Also look at AudioCapture here
http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/media/index.html